# iPhone SDK: How to dynamically create view controller with NIB_A?

Tags: iphone

How can I dynamically create a view controller with a NIB file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still need help. I wanted to post what I was working on. I don't know the syntax for specifying what NIB one would like loaded.

Thanks.

```
OptionAController *otherVC = [[OptionAController alloc] init ????];     
[self presentModalViewController otherVC animated:YES]; 
[otherVC release];
```

Comment: Um... ianh just gave you the exact answer you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Worked like a champ. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[[OptionAController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NameOfNIB" bundle:nil]`.  You can find this method in Apple's [UIViewController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW15).